# Integrating ng-admin 2 into JHipser

Tags: webpack, jhipster, ng-admin

I've been trying to use ng-admin 2 instead of standard admin panel in generated JHipster app but couldn't make it work. Has anyone ever swapped out the standard JHipster admin panel for something else for example ng-admin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to change the frontend framework to something else, but there is no "really" switch, which acts like a single command turning the existing frontend to something different. The closest thing is a set of [JHipster Modules](https://jhipster.github.io/modules/marketplace), where people are offering similar things. There will be React support soon.

But if you want to use ng-admin, you will have to implement it manually. If you do so, you might consider doing that as a JHipster module

Comment: As I understand it the admin module is using Spring Boot Actuator, right? And some front-end is generated to use it? So it wouldn't be that hard to remove all the front-end stuff using Actuator and put ng-admin into it? Of course with adjustments.

Comment: IMHO it is a matter of rewrite. you might still use the webpack config and some stuff from angular, like services, which don't depend on anything.  Hard or not hard? Depends on how deep you are in ng. But I guess it's a bunch of work